# View photos in a vertical bar from database

Tags: asp.net

i want to view photos in vertical bar from database and when i click in any photos of them it will be displayded in full size in center of page

please can any one help me how i can do it

Comment: We're going to need more information to help you.  You want to create a web site that will connect to a database(what flavor). display a list of thumbnail photos, and then when you click on them, they expand or open in a new window or a new div?

Comment: We definitely need to see some code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to bind your images to a GridView and then use the jQuery [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) plugin.

Comment: Excellent question.  I'm going to Google it right now and find out.